How to start using the debugger in IntelliJ IDEA
I'm in the process of switching over from VS Code and I am having issue starting the debugger.
I'm clicking on the green play button next to my npm script and pressed on the debugger option. The debugger is started but all my breakpoints are not attached. If I run code that has the debugger set on it, it won't pause and let me dive into it line by line. What is going on?

What project is it - frontend or backend? What do your launch configurations in VSCode look like?

You can add new configuration near the green hammer,
and choose Nodejs, next you will add Javascript file is main.js in dist folder,
my config like this:

this case you need to build before debug to re-generate dist folder
Or
you can run the script in package.json, add task in Before launch, search run npm script, 
in scripts, choose what you want to run
